# How to redirect users on click no matter where they click on a page in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I am investigating a piece of malware on a free movie site. The malware redirects user to some other page **no matter where one clicks**.

I tried deleting the header tag, div with main id tag and footer tag and eventually the whole body tag but the redirection was still effective. Therefore I came to conclusion that the malicious func is triggered on click not attached to any specific elements in the HTML.

My question is how is that done?

(if you want to try yourself, just google fmovie)

Comment: @Snow - Sure, here you go https://ww3.fmovie.sc/search-query/superman/. Do let me know if you get any insights from it.

Comment: the virus source is here `https://ilivaris.pw/rr44aiahDEp/15863`, and its of course heavily obfuscated. it is injected via script tag on the page where you view movies

Comment: @r3wt, thank you so much bro. I am aware of the malicious source. Do you know how the injection is done w/o any onclick?

Comment: @GangFang i deobfuscated the source, and there are a couple lines where it walks the document attaching a click listener to every non text node

Comment: @r3wt, wow that's cool! Did you use any tools for deobfuscation?

Comment: i used https://lelinhtinh.github.io/de4js/

but i can't actually deobfuscate it, however just having the code pretty printed allowed me to find all the malicious stuff it does. its quite alot. i would probably start by base64 decoding the items in the array at top of the script to see what each thing is.

Comment: after further analysis, i have determined this code was 99.999% likely to have been obfuscated using https://obfuscator.io/, and there is no known deobfuscator that works on their proprietary obfuscator.

Comment: @r3wt - Thanks again, just looked into that and learnt some new stuff!

Answer (score 3):

I think the whole site is a scam designed to serve malware and nothing else. I can't figure out a way to play videos even when the ads and new windows are disabled. The closest I could get was to a "Play Video" interface which refused to play but also said "You must create a Free Account to stream this movie/episode", which linked somewhere *offsite* that instructed the user to download malware.

This isn't a video-hosting site that's been taken over by malware-distributors - it's a malware distributor site posing as a video-hosting site.

If you want to prevent it from opening windows, if it were me, I'd write a userscript to monkeypatch the page *before* the page has a chance to run anything. All you have to do is overwrite `window.open` with a function that doesn't open a window, and nothing will be opened:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         No Window Opening
// @match        https://ww3.fmovie.sc/*
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

window.open = () => null;
```

You'll need a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).

The userscript needs to run *as soon as possible*, before anything on the site loads (otherwise the ad script will be able to take a reference to the original `window.open` before you overwrite it). If the userscript isn't running in time, it won't work. If this is your experience, go into Tampermonkey settings, open Advanced options, scroll to the bottom, and set (Experimental) Inject Mode to Instant.

The ad script saves a reference to `window.open` to a top-level variable named `glxopen`, so another option would be to overwrite `window.glxopen` with a getter that returns a no-op function, and a setter that does nothing.

Another option would be to completely block the URL / domain that's serving the script with the ads - you could use your preferred version of Adblock to block `https://ilivaris.pw/rr44aiahDEp/15863`, or add `https://ilivaris.pw/` to your Hosts file.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wonder if the script is inserted into the page by bad guys or a part of the site itself. This is inside the body tag: `<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="//ilivaris.pw/rr44aiahDEp/15863"></script>`

Comment: Looking at the site more closely, I'm pretty sure the whole site is designed to serve malware. `This isn't a video-hosting site that's been taken over by malware-distributors - it's a malware distributor site posing as a video-hosting site.` The "bad guys" are the creators of the site themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Use the debuger and pause the website so you can see what has been triggered. Here from Firefox. `Step in` `Step over` to continue Execution of the page.

[image]

Comment: Thank you fubar I appreciate it. I did the same thing in Chrome. The problem is the code is obfuscated and in one line so it's hard to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it could be achieved simply by adding a click event to the whole window. The malicious code probably does just that but it has been obfuscated so it took sometime to find out.

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sometext;
});
```